# Wrong css file applying Cart Page and Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, css, xml

I am new to Magento. I am working with v. 1.9.2 CE.  I have created my own package("TTO") and theme ("ttoTheme"), applied it and its working fine except for the Cart, Checkout, Account and Registration pages. I haven't tested the email templates yet.

The Home, Category, and Product pages are using the correct stylesheet:

*.../skin/frontend/TTO/ttoTheme/css/styles.css*

The Cart, Checkout, Account and Registration pages are using the fallback stylesheet in the rwd/default theme:

*.../skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css*

Also, these pages are breaking my logo's and images by following the wrong path:

*img scr=".../skin/frontend/base/default/images/media/main_logo.png" alt="Nnnn Nnnnn Nnn" class="large"*

Where as the home, category and product pages use the correct path:

*img scr=".../skin/frontend/TTO/ttoTheme/images/media/main_logo.png" alt="Nnnn Nnnnn Nnn" class="large"*

So my question is how would I go about correcting this? My gut says is the offending pages' XML files need to be copied from rwd/default, modified, and then added to my theme. This is just a guess but if it happens to be correct, I need an example.  Can someone provide some input on this?

Comment: did you set your theme from system -> configuration  design tab. current packge TTO and Default ttoTheme/..

Comment: I did yes.  All other pages seem to be applying the correct css file.  I am working with CE 1.9.2.  My 1.9.1 on XAMPP where I developed the theme, doesn't have this issue.

Comment: going to try reinstalling.  perhaps I screwed up somewhere in the process.  Even with changing back to the RWD theme, its still calling the wrong css files, this time from the TTO package??!!!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and close the question.  I never really found an answer to the issue however the reinstall worked to solve my issue.  I can only assume that I screwed up in the install somewhere.  It also crosses my mind that the my custom theme caused some sort of conflict somewhere in the code. Perhaps it wasn't forward compatible with respect to the css.  Either way, the reinstall worked fine.